# Writing logs to both terminal and file

Tags: go

I have this function to write logs to both the terminal and a log file:

```golang
// Run an executable and print its log in real-time and print its log into a file too.
func RunWithLog(pthExe string, arg []string, fLog *os.File, dir string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(pthExe, arg...)
    if dir != "" {
        cmd.Dir = dir
    }

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(4)

    go streamRealTime(stdout, &wg)
    go streamRealTime(stderr, &wg)

    go streamToLogFile(stdout, fLog, &wg)
    go streamToLogFile(stderr, fLog, &wg)

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    wg.Wait()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    return err
}

func streamRealTime(output io.ReadCloser, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(output)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Print(scanner.Text())
    }
    err := scanner.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: write log to terminal: %s", err.Error())
    }
}

func streamToLogFile(output io.ReadCloser, fLog *os.File, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(output)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        _, err := fLog.WriteString(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: write log to file: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }
    err := scanner.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: write log to file: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

The above function is called:

```golang
    // Log file.
    fLog, err := os.OpenFile(pathLog, os.O_APPEND, os.ModeAppend)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer fLog.Close()

    err = RunWithLog(pathExe, []string{"-b"}, fLog, workDir)
    // ...
```

## Problem

The problem is that some log lines are printed to the terminal and some lines are printed to the file, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

## Question

How can I make sure that all the log lines are printed to both the terminal and file?

Comment: I think you're have a race condition since you're creating two readers for one input (stdout, stderr respectively have two consuming readers each). Why not use one function to log to both console and file? Alternatively, you could create another pipe.

Comment: @FObersteiner Right. I got you. Makes sense. I'm going to test it...

Comment: @FObersteiner Thanks :) It worked. I explained the details in a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs are printed to both a terminal and a file by this:

```golang
// Run an executable and print its log real-time and print its log into a file too.
func RunWithLog(pthExe string, arg []string, fLog *os.File, dir string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(pthExe, arg...)
    if dir != "" {
        cmd.Dir = dir
    }

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go streamLogs(stdout, fLog, &wg)
    go streamLogs(stderr, fLog, &wg)

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    wg.Wait()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    return err
}

// Stream logs to both terminal and a file.
func streamLogs(output io.ReadCloser, fLog *os.File, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(output)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        // Stream to terminal:
        fmt.Print(scanner.Text())
        // Stream to a file:
        _, err := fLog.WriteString(scanner.Text())
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error: write log to file: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }
    err := scanner.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: write log to terminal: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

## Test

Logs are the same:

[image: Screenshots]