# How do I use Go Fiber's logger to output to both stdout and a log file?

Tags: go, go-fiber

Here is the existing logger using a log file called `logFile`

```golang
app.Use(logger.New(logger.Config{
    Format:     "[LOG] ${time} ${status} - ${latency} ${method} ${path}\n",
    TimeFormat: "2006/01/2 15:04:05",
    Output:     logFile,
}))
```

However, I also want to log to os.Stdout.

Is there a way using Fiber's Config to log to both at the same time?
Should I use the io.Writer interface to make my own Writer that logs to a log file and to stdout?

I have so far looked through the following resources and can't find someone doing something similar. I couldn't find more relevant resources about this.

- https://docs.gofiber.io/api/log
- https://docs.gofiber.io/api/middleware/logger
- [Writing logs to both terminal and file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112541/writing-logs-to-both-terminal-and-file)

Comment: `Should I use the io.Writer interface to make my own Writer that logs to a log file and to stdout?` *Yes! if you insist!*, in most cases it's better to use stdout for debugging and use log file for product, if not it will be a big trouble, you should handle nohup output in production which is exactly the same as log file, **don't do such thing!**

Comment: Yea, I went with logging to the screen in development for debugging and logging to a file for production to not clutter up stdout.

Comment: I think it's not possible to do so without a custom logger. If you're on Linux, you can use commands like `tee` or `tail -f` on the log file once you start the API